# In VB.NET evaluate 0.70 to be equal to .7

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sqldatasource, comparison-operators

I am comparing a value that the user entered into a DataGridView cell - which, coming from an Editing Control will be a string to start with - with a decimal value from the data source (defined as decimal(3,2)).

How can I evaluate a user-entered value of ".7", for example, to be equal to the database value of 0.70?

Comment: if ".7" is string, convert or parse to decimal and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CDec` function to convert a string value to a decimal. e.g.

```
If CDec(".7") = 0.7 Then
    ' This will be true
End If
```

If you aren't sure that the value entered by the user will be a valid decimal, then you should use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim value As Decimal = 0
If Decimal.TryParse(".7", value) Then
    If value = 0.7 Then
        ' This will be true
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = ".7"
Dim test As Double = Double.Parse(str)
MessageBox.Show(test)
```

You can use Decimal.Parse as indicated by Plutonix as well.